# R: Default cut-off value predict rpart to turn probabilities into classes?

Tags: r, class, probability, rpart

I'm using the `rpart` package to make a prediction model. If I use the `predict` function and set the `type="class"`, it automatically generates the classes based on the probabilities.

I would like to know the cut-off probability value on which this is based, but can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`rpart` is based on CART the algorithm presented in "Breiman L., Friedman J. H., Olshen R. A., and Stone, C. J. (1984) Classification and Regression Trees". It does not use probabilities to decide how to split nodes, so there is no such threshold. Instead, CART uses a measure of impurity of the nodes.  `rpart` uses either Gini (the default) or Information Gain to measure impurity. There *are* some thresholds that you can set using `rpart.control`. The three main ones are `cp` `minsplit` and `minbucket` that are described with `rpart.control`.

Breiman's book is the primary reference on this, but some additional details are available from 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning)

Answer (score 0):

It assigns the class based on the probability values. If its between predicting 1's and 0's, the default cut-off value is 0.5 and similarly it'' vary based on the number of categories you have for the response variable.